# Linux load balancing between multiple interfaces

Tags: linux, debian, routing, load-balancing

I have a Debian 9 Server with multiple virtual interfaces (eth0:0->4). I need to send messages to a set of different urls and i'd like to use a random interface as the source IP for each message, ideally in a round robin way.

What would be the best practice to do this ?

Comment: What protocol for message? http?  Nginx revers proxy https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/load_balancing.html + policy routing - it depends how networking configured

Comment: @gapsf I want to round robin the source IP, not the destination

Comment: Its not easy task and highly depends on configuration and networking. For example what is "virtual interfaces" in your case? Just several ip on on interface eth0 or its a different interfaces? If all ip on eth0 from same subnet you will have more troubles with routing. If it TCP you need route not packets but outgoing connections.

Comment: Its a kernel decides from what interface packets outgo consulting routing tables and routing policy database. It is possible with routing policy database but you need some criteria like dst ip or port, dccp, fwmark and somehow mark outgoing connections by you app or by iptables  to later route them via different interfaces.

Comment: Actually, the virtual interfaces are eth:0 to 4. They are configured to be IP Failovers on a OVH Public Cloud instance. Therefore, they are public IPs.
I don't know if it's possible to have a routing policy with round robin.
I looked into interface bonding but it seems I need to have different interfaces names to make it work

Comment: 4.2.2. Load balancing https://tldp.org/HOWTO/Adv-Routing-HOWTO/lartc.rpdb.multiple-links.html